Photoshop: non-destructively edit layer masks
I have a layer, and I want to apply a layer mask to it, but I want to non-destructively edit the layer mask: i.e. apply levels or curves non-desctructively to the layer mask only, so I can edit the levels or curves of the mask at any point.

I need to non-destructively edit the levels and/or curves of the layer mask, so that any change I do can be reverted or changed at any time, without permanently changing the layer mask's pixels. I know I can work on duplicate copies of things, either by duplicating layers or entire files, but that's not what I'm after.
